# useCallback equivalent in React class component

Tags: reactjs, usecallback

I have a large code base in React class components and some are so complex, that I do not want to refactor them to React functional components. For one function, I need memoization, so my question is:

**Is there an equivalent for React functional component's useCallback in React classic components?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have to use something like `static getDerivedStateFromProps()` to listen on the changes in the variable, and maybe use `shouldComponentUpdate()` as a workaround/manual memoization.
In `getDerivedStateFromProps()` you would call your function in case of changes in the variables you want, and In `shouldComponentUpdate()` you should return false if your logic doesn't match.